# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installer Ubiquity crashes when scale factor > 100%

Tags: system-installation, 18.04, crash, ubiquity

Every time I use Ubiquity to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the installer crashes after the last input panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found after many attempts that the scaling factor is what caused the crash on my machine. By default it is 200 % and this makes Ubiquity crash. Changing to 100 % (even just before validating last input panel) prevents it from crashing.

Obviously this a bug.

Comment: Please raise a bug report on launchpad; or if one already exists add yourself to another person being affected by said bug.